# get('security.context')->isGranted in functional test

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I want do one functional test over on service Symfony2. The idea is call before to the controller and after that, load the service with the function. The function is this one:

```php
function save($title,$description,$setId,$html,$validate,$articles){
    $articles = explode(',', $articles);

    if (false === $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        throw new \Exception("Not allowed");
    }else{
        $profileId  = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
        $userName   = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getUserName();
    }
}
```

and now my test code is :

```php
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET','/sets/save',
            array(
                    "title"=>"rtyui",
                    "description"=>"aksdjhashdkjahskjdh",
                    "set_id"=>"",
                    "html"=>"",
                    "validate"=>1,
                    "articels"=>"3,4"
                )
        );
```

but doesn't work already that I have this lines:

```php
if (false === $this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        throw new \Exception("Not allowed");
```

Now, the question is, how i can do the validation process? I've tried to do this validation process as show the documentation:

```php
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'username',
    'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'pa$$word',
));
```

but I got the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also you can login user by Security Token:

```php
$client = static::createClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
$container->get('security.context')->setToken(
    new UsernamePasswordToken(
        $user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles()
    )
);
```

Where:

1. `$user` - instance of User entity with role `ROLE_USER`,
2. `main` - your security provider name

Comment: just use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)